# R - How to add 2 different dim tables by groups

Tags: r

I have two data frames like these:

```
Group   V1     V2
a       a1     a2
a       a3     a4
b       b1     b2
b       b3     b4
b       b5     b6
```

and

```
Group   V1     V2
a       a5     a6
b       b7     b8
```

I want to obtain a df like this:

```
Group   V1        V2
a       a1+a5     a2+a6
a       a3+a5     a4+a6
b       b1+b7     b2+b8
b       b3+b7     b4+b8
b       b5+b7     b6+b8
```

Can you please instruct me how to do this in R? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - you can dump content of your dataframes  (df) using dput(head(df, 20)) - this will give 20 rows of your dataframe, you can paste the output here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, `b2` are numbers and you want to add them in final dataframe, you can join `df1` and `df2` by `Group` and add the corresponding values.

This can be done in base R :

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'Group'), V1 = V1.x + V1.y, 
                V2 = V2.x + V2.y)[names(df1)]

#  Group V1 V2
#1     a  6  8
#2     a  8 10
#3     b  8 10
#4     b 10 12
#5     b 12 14
```

Or in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'Group') %>%
   mutate(V1 = V1.x + V1.y, V2 = V2.x + V2.y) %>%
   select(names(df1))
```

**data**

Used this dummy data :

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), V1 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L), V2 = c(2L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Group = structure(1:2, .Label = c("a", "b"), 
class = "factor"), V1 = c(5L, 7L), V2 = c(6L, 8L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```